# How to remove files in my git-svn checkout, which are still present after dcommit?

Tags: git, git-svn

I have cloned a `svn` repository using the `git svn clone` command. On my local working copy I made some changes and removed a couple of files. After I checked in the changes locally with `git commit` it was time to push the changes to the repository, which I did with

```
git svn dcommit
git svn rebase
```

All of the new files and directories have been pushed to the repository, but the removed files are still in the repository on the host system! In other words: Even after `git svn rebase` (which, as far as I know is the command to fetch all changes from the repository) my local copy and the repository are substantial different!

To make myself more clear: I have the repository on the remote/host computer which is the central place with many different repositories people have access to. I made a checkout of one of the repositories to my local computer, made some changes (i.e. removed files), and then wanted to push/send/save my changes to the central repository. New files were created, but file I have removed are still present on the central repository on the central host.

What do I need to do to make my local checkout and the repository on the host system equal?

Comment: Do you add the change of removing files to index before you `git commit`?

Comment: For each file I did a `git rm` before the `git commit`. Is that what you meant or something else?

Comment: `git svn rebase` is not the command to fetch changes from the repository.. that would be `git fetch` (and then maybe a rebase or merge - whatever you prefer)

Comment: `git fetch` does not work (`fatal: No remote repository specified. ...`) and `git svn fetch` does not change my local checkout of the repository. And I STILL have unwanted files in the repository on the host system which I want to remove properly with `git svn`. How to do that? This was my original question...

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the `svn` repository, unable to have handled the `remove` statements correctly.

I do not think there is anything wrong with the stated procedure, but here is the procedure to 'manually' remove the unwanted directories (assuming only directories are left with all files removed properly within.)

1. Check out the svn repository

   ```
   svn co <e.g. link to trunk path>
   ```
2. Remove all directories manually in the local checkout (which will not remove them in the local file structure immediately)

   ```
   svn rm <directory>
   ```
3. Commit the changes to the repository, after which the changes become visible in the repository and in the local file structure

   ```
   svn commit -m "<Sense-full message>"
   ```